# ASP .net performance analysis of web pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance

I am working in ASP.net 3.5 MVC application.

1) Is there any standard for the response size returned by the web request( Say a good response size is 10k) and if it is more than that we may need to design the web page to return 10K or less.

Sometimes when I see a response more than 60K I feel like that page might struggle a lot when more users are accessing over the internet.

2)Also is there any way to monitor the session in InProc session state mode. Say monitoring the session size occupied by the application. Such measures can enable me to improve the performance of the application.

Any thoughts or comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use IIS compression to reduce data transmitted via the wire. In my experience, this really helps tremendously and fairly simple to enable in IIS.

You can use tools like YSlow and PageSpeed (both are firefox extensions) to get a feel on how fast/performance wise for your site. There are other things you can do to increase front-end performance other than reducing amount of data (Both YSlow and PageSpeed will tell you those).

Answer (score 2):

If data needs to be returned it needs to be returned. Of course there is pagination, which might help in certain cases. In general there isn't any major difference whether you output 60Kb in a single page, or 6Kb in 10 separate pages. The client should be worried more about that.
The server transmits even more when it comes to javascript, images, flash... HTML is just a tiny part of it all.